# What occured on the 2nd of Shevat and the 2nd of Av?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I am aware that both the 15th of Shevat and the 15th of Av are holidays mentioned in the Talmud.

But each year, one of my friends sends me a greeting email on the 2nd of Shevat saying "Happy TWO Bishevat" and on the 2nd of Av he sends me another greeting saying "Happy TWO B'Av."

I couldn't locate anything in the Talmud, Shulchan Aruch or any Jewish sources explaining what these two holidays commemorate. Any ideas?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 1):

If you learn the Gzera shava two two you can discover that they eaten matsot in a Succa. In French this law is called  tout ou rien (too oo rien = all or nothing)

We use this principle for a Gzera shava mufnet mishne tsdadim.